# How do I figure out how many N-m it takes to move a man on a skateboard?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

Given that the skateboard is on a flat surface, and let's say that the man weights 150lbs. How would I figure out how many N-m it takes to move that man? Does the wheel size matter?

Ignore friction of wheels and other environmental variables for a second, I am trying to figure out how one calculates how much N-m it takes to move a person? Are there other variables I need to know?

I am trying to ask this question without sounding ignorant, but it is true that I lack knowledge in physics. Please excuse me if I do sound ignorant.

Comment: Hi Johnston. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: @Qmechanic thanks for the clarification. I would agree with http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7162/should-we-rename-the-homework-policy that it is a source of initial confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A moving skateboarder on a flat slope has only kinetic energy. The kinetic energy of you and your skateboard is (1/2)mv^2 where m is rhe total mass of you and your skateboard. Both you and your skateboard start out with 0J (or 0 Nm) of kinetic energy. This means you have to do work on the skateboard to give it kinetic energy. How much work? Exactly (1/2)mv^2 Joules. Also, everyone who knows things once learnt them for the first time; it's fine if it's your first encounter with this. Anyway, I hope this helped answer your question, and have a nice day.